# What amount of data does select (2) guarantee to be able to be written to a file without blocking

Tags: c, linux, select, system-calls

`select` (2) (amongst other things) tells me whether I can write to a fd of a file without blocking.  However, does it guarentee me that I can write a full 4096 bytes without blocking?

**Note** I am interested in normal files on disk.  Not sockets or the like.

In other words: does `select` signal when we can just write one single byte to a file fd without blocking, *or* does it signal when we can write *n* (4096, ... ?) bytes to a file fd without blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever `select()` indicates that your file is ready, you can try writing N bytes, for any N>0. `write()` will return the number of bytes actually written. If it equals N, you can write again. If it's less than N, then the next write will block.

**Note** Normal files on disk don't block. Sockets, pipes and terminals do.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged this "Linux", so what does the kernel source code tell you? It should be pretty easy to read the syscall implementation to find when select decides to treat a file descriptor as ready for writing.

If you're worried about blocking, though, you're doing it wrong. If you don't want to block, use `O_NONBLOCK` or equivalents. Even if `select` did guarantee a certain number of bytes could be written without blocking, that would only be true at the time `select` returns; it might not necessarily be true by the time you actually perform the write.

Answer (score 3):

> Note I am interested in normal files on disk. Not sockets or the like.

select does not "work" with normal files, only sockets/pipes/ttys and possibly others, but not regular files. For regular files select will always signal the file descriptor as readable/writable - thus it is a rather useless exercise to use select with files.

note that that applies to other io multiplexing facilities as well, such as poll/epoll. [AIO](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/aio.h.html) will do asynchonous io to regular files, but operating system support might vary, and it is a rather complex api to use

As to how much data you can write, there is no promise. 4096 is no magical number that select assumes you can write without blocking, when applied to filedescriptors where using select does make sense (sockets/pipes/etc.) . Because you can't know how much data you can write without blocking, you should always set the file descriptor to non-blocking, record how much was actually written as indicated by the return value of write/send and start writing from that point the next time select indicates you can write data again.

Answer (score 1):

select() only promises that the applicable call can be made without blocking, it does not guarantee an I/O amount (4096) in your case.  Since select() can be used with different types of descriptors (file, sockets, serial connections, etc.) you may notice that for disk operations the observed behavior is that a full buffer can always be written, but again this is specific to the particular underlying operation and not a promise of select().